# How to make an input type text look like select dropdown?

Tags: jquery, html, css, input

Is there any way by which I can make an input type=text element look like a dropdown? Currently I have a text box which when clicked I am displaying options using jquery and div. I want the text box to have a drop down icon to make it exactly look like a regular dropdown.

Also since different browsers have different dropdown icon is there a way to use the same dropdown icon that the browser provides?

Note:
I have to apply some css to the option values before displaying it which I cant do using regular dropdown. That is why I have used div and jquery to display the option values.

Comment: use dropdown icon as background of your textbox.

Comment: Use a `select` element instead then? Don't see why you'd use an `input[type=text]` when you want the appearance of a `select`. If you can't directly alter the HTML use JS to convert it.

Comment: @powerbuoy I have explained the reason in the question now

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai Will try it. But could you please elaborate it in the answer section? thanks:)

Comment: With jQuery, you can always apply CSS changes you want at the point of creation; even at the very click of the element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is when **:after** pseudoelement gets in handy. Wrap your input in DIV.

```
 #wrap:after {
     content:arrow icon image;
 }
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/17w6kap6/1/)

But there's no way you could use different CSS style sheet for different browser yet, so only one type of icon so far.

Answer (score 8):

Try this example!

```
<div>Choose a browser from this list:</div>
<input list="browsers" />
<datalist id="browsers">
  <option value="Chrome">
  <option value="Firefox">
  <option value="Internet Explorer">
  <option value="Opera">
  <option value="Safari">
</datalist>
```

```html
<div>Choose a browser from this list:</div>
    <input list="browsers" />
    <datalist id="browsers">
      <option value="Chrome">
      <option value="Firefox">
      <option value="Internet Explorer">
      <option value="Opera">
      <option value="Safari">
    </datalist>
```

Comment: Maybe I misinterpret the question?

Comment: I have to apply some css to the option values before displaying it which I cant do using your code or by using regular dropdown. That is why I have used div and jquery to display the option values.

Comment: I don't know if it solved the question but this is the exact magic I have been looking for. This kind of input has always baffled me.